# Which key mappings will move cursor up and down one true line at a time?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I use VS Code to write markdown (among other things), and would like to be able to use the keyboard mappings I'm used to when navigating text in other text editors, like TextEdit on MacOS, or the window in which I'm typing this question. These key maps include:

- "alt+up" for move cursor up a line
- "alt+down" for move cursor down a line
- "shift+alt+up" for move cursor up and select
- "shift+alt+down" for move cursor down and select

When I write "up a line," I mean up through the "true" lines, not wrapped lines. Currently the up and down arrows on their own will move the cursor through the wrapped lines. This is fine, but I'd like to be able to move up and down through the true lines, too.

I know that I can remap these combinations manually in VS Code, but I'm not sure what to remap them *to*. In other words, what are the VS Code functions for moving the cursor up and down a true line, and moving it while selecting the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you mean by a "true line" (but I may be wrong on that).  In your `keybindings.json` try this for example:

```
{
  "key": "alt+up",            // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "cursorMove",
  "args": {
    "to": "up",
    "by": "line",            // you can get intellisense for the options (Ctrl+Space)
    // "select": true        // false is the default
  },
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
{
  "key": "alt+down",
  "command": "cursorMove",
  "args": {
    "to": "down",
    "by": "line",
    // "select": true
  },
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
```